# Is moving without shutting down good for MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

My friends told me,while I am moving to other places, I can just close my rMBP without shutting down the computer.

Is it a right concept?
Will it damage hardwares?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's perfectly safe to do, it's best to wait until the hard drive spins down and the sleep light activates before moving it. On a MacBook with an SSD (like the Retina or Air), you don't even need to wait for that, since there's no spinning hard drive.